# How to enable a default button and make it non-editable in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to set the default value of an android button enabled and non-editable. The below codes in the xml file does not produce anything whereas the codes in the java file shows error, saying can't find symbol under the . between mPref and putBoolean.  How I can fix the issue?

My xml code is:

```
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:enabled="true"
        app:key="@string/key_add_timestamp"
        app:title="@string/timestamp"
        tools:visibility="gone" />
            
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:enabled="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:enabled="true"
        app:key="@string/key_add_user"
        app:summary="@string/your_email"
        app:title="@string/user"
        tools:visibility="gone" />
```

And in the MainActivity.java:

```
mPref.putBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.key_add_timestamp), true).apply();
            mPref.putBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.key_add_user), true).apply();
```

[image: Android app settings layout]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default value as ON, try this:

```
android:checked="true"
```